# Custom Post Type Single page showing Complete Blank

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello my wordpress theme's post type `listings` single post showing a blank page.But on another 3 hosting it works.
A complete blank even page title not showing.

I tried to solve the problem by :

1. WP_DEBUG set to true
2. Removing The hierarchical
3. setting error_reporting(-1)
4. Deactivating All plugins
5. Setting the theme Newly

But all of those steps gone vein.

link http://www.thefeastbox.in/listings/thai/

My custom post type register:

```
public function register_restaurant_listing()
{
    register_post_type('listings', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
            'singular_name' => __('Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'thefoody') ,
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
            'edit' => __('Edit', 'thefoody') ,
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
            'new_item' => __('New Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
            'view' => __('View Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
            'view_item' => __('View Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
            'search_items' => __('Search Restaurant listings', 'thefoody') ,
            'not_found' => __('No Restaurant listings found', 'thefoody') ,
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Restaurant listings found in Trash', 'thefoody') ,
            'parent' => __('Parent Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
        ) ,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail'
        ) ,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-megaphone'
    ));
}
```

Comment: On this page, turn on error reporting: `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` Should tell you what's wrong. If your display errors is off, I don't think `error_reporting()` will work.

Comment: @Rasclatt tried but not works.or shows any error :(